# Integration test - remove the mu plugins in the test

Tags: testing, unit-tests

As a recurring theme these past few questions I asked, I'm doing integration testing and want to check the `activate` static method that gets called in my `register_activation_hook` in the main plugin file

```
<?php
namespace My_Plugin;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, [ Includes\Activator::class, 'activate' ] );

( new Includes\Main() )->run();
```

Now the kick is - in my bootstrap.php file, as is the usual case, I had to add

```
/**
 * Manually load the plugin being tested.
 */
function _manually_load_plugin() {
  require dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) . '/advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php';
  require dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/my-plugin.php';
}

tests_add_filter( 'muplugins_loaded', '_manually_load_plugin' );
```

ACF Pro because my plugin is depending on it.

And the real issue here is that since they are loaded as a MU plugins, during the test, they are always active, so I cannot deactivate them, and test if the `activate` method is doing what it needs to do.

Any way to test this?

Comment: So you're creating a testing situation (putting the plugins in the MU folder) that does not reflect the later production situation and is more complex? What's the benefit of that?

Comment: When you run `wp scaffold plugin-tests` you set up the integration test suite for the plugin you want to test. This is basically what is provided to me when I ran that command. If there is another way of doing this I'm all ears. My understanding was that this is done so that the plugin is loaded in the test environment...

Comment: Have you had a look at this: https://github.com/JDGrimes/wpppb/. Even though that's about unit testing, not integration testing.

Comment: No, I did not look at that, but I already have my tests set up, and other tests are working fine (both unit and integration).

Comment: My approach has been to leave bootstrap alone and call the functions manually inside the tests (just call the function name). I realize this is a bit of a hack as not everything that happens in a registration hook can be run twice, but maybe it will help you find a way to do what you want. HTH